# 403 error just for directory, and not files in the directory

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, directory, http-status-code-403

Let's say I have a directory on my site...

```
http://test.com/images/
```

...and I want to show a 403 forbidden error if somebody tries to access it. So I would use....

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
```

...in the .htaccess file in my main directory. However, how could I make it so that it just displays the 403 error when the user is trying to view the directory directly. So if I wanted to visit...

```
http://test.com/images/test.png
```

...it would work and I could see the image, but if I visited `http://test.com/images/`, I would get a 403 error. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What web server are you using?  You just need to disallow directory browsing on the webserver.

Comment: @RobM I use Host Gator (Linux CentOS).

Comment: are you that this "http://test.com/images/" specifies the directory, as opposed to specifying all the files in that directory? Doesn't this do it "http://test.com/images"  ??

Comment: @user2680030 I think you mean your provider is Host Gator. The web server you are using is Apache running on CentOS. :)  Accordingly, my answer below will work for you. Unless you have some special need, it's a best practice to disable directory browsing anyway for all directories in your app. The solution below will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache, you should disable directory browsing in the config. 
Find your httpd.conf (likely at /etc/apache/httpd.conf), and remove 'Indexes' from a line that will look like this:

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

so that it looks like this:

```
Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Then restart Apache.

BTW, that kind of question is better asked here instead: 
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/